# How to extract NDVI values into polygon vector map with QGIS

Tags: qgis, ndvi

I have calculated the NDVI values of a satellite image using the raster calculator. Now I need to have these NDVI values extracted into the attribute table of my polygon vector file. Is there a plug-in that would help?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with the [zonal statistic plugin](http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_zonal_statistics.html) where you compute the mean NDVI for each polygon.